# How correctly to set up server part through Java socket?

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I have written server and client part, see code:

```
//this I run on my firt PC
public class TCPServer {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    TCPServer server = new TCPServer();
    server.run();
 }

 public void run() throws Exception{
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(6789);
    Socket SOCK = socket.accept();
    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(SOCK.getInputStream()));

    String msg = BR.readLine();
    System.out.println(msg);

    if(msg != null){
        PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(SOCK.getOutputStream());
        PS.print("MESSAGE RECEIVED");
    }
 }
}


//This I run on my notebook
public class TCPClient {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

            TCPClient client = new TCPClient();
            client.run();
        }

        public void run() throws Exception{
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.88.77",6789);
            PrintStream PS = new  PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            PS.print("Hello from GLADIS VLADLEN");

            BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            String msg = BR.readLine();
            System.out.println(msg);

        }
}
```

After running this applications nothing happens. And only after I stop Client app message is received by server part. Why this happens? I try to turn off FireWall but this don't help me.

Comment: You need to `flush()` the outstream after writing to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the server and client are reading a line using `BufferedReader#readLine()`. However the `PrintStream` is sending characters without the line terminator.

Try calling `println` instead of `print`.